# NestJS- Trying to Upload Base64 on Azure Blob Storage

Tags: nestjs, azure-storage

Trying to upload basee64 string of image to Azure Storage in nestJS, it's following function uploads empty image and empty content.

```
    async uploadBase64Image() {
        const image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/2wCEAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMEAwMEBQgFBQQEBQoHBwYIDAoMDAsKCwsNDhIQDQ4RDgsLEBYQERMUFRUVDA8XGB......';
        const newFileName = (Math.random() + 1).toString(36).substring(2);
        const base64Data = image as string;
        const [, imageExtension] = base64Data.split(';')[0].split('/');
        const filename = newFileName + '.' + imageExtension;

        const base64_img = image.replace(/^data:image\/jpeg;base64,/, '');
        const imgBuffer = Readable.from(Buffer.from(base64_img, 'base64'));
        const blobName = `images/slider/${filename}`;
        // const stream = Readable.from(base64_img); //Tried that too
        const containerClient: ContainerClient = (
          this.blobServiceClient as BlobServiceClient
        ).getContainerClient('public');
        const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);
        // await blockBlobClient.create
        await blockBlobClient.uploadStream(
          imgBuffer,
          this.uploadOptions.bufferSize,
          this.uploadOptions.maxBuffers,
          { blobHTTPHeaders: { blobContentType: 'image/jpeg' } }
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use [`uploadData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blockblobclient?view=azure-node-latest#@azure-storage-blob-blockblobclient-uploaddata) method instead of `uploadStream`. Your code would be something like:

```js
async uploadBase64Image() {
  const image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/2wCEAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMEAwMEBQgFBQQEBQoHBwYIDAoMDAsKCwsNDhIQDQ4RDgsLEBYQERMUFRUVDA8XGB......';
  const newFileName = (Math.random() + 1).toString(36).substring(2);
  const base64Data = image as string;
  const [, imageExtension] = base64Data.split(';')[0].split('/');
  const filename = newFileName + '.' + imageExtension;

  const base64_img = image.replace(/^data:image\/jpeg;base64,/, '');
  const imgBuffer = Buffer.from(base64_img, 'base64');
  const blobName = `images/slider/${filename}`;
  // const stream = Readable.from(base64_img); //Tried that too
  const containerClient: ContainerClient = (
    this.blobServiceClient as BlobServiceClient
  ).getContainerClient('public');
  const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);
  // await blockBlobClient.create
  await blockBlobClient.uploadStream(
    imgBuffer,
    { blobHTTPHeaders: { blobContentType: 'image/jpeg' } }
  );
}
```